# Setting DataPropertyName in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding

I have a problem with setting a correct data property for DataPropertyName of DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I have a BindingSource and I set its DataSource to BindingList of custom objects. These objects have properties which I'd like to assign as columns in DataGridView (pluginsDataGrid):

```
var source = new BindingSource {DataSource = _plugins};
pluginsDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
pluginsDataGrid.DataSource = source;
```

Everything's fine when I have a simple string as a property - it is Name:

```
 using (var nameCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn())
 {
      nameCol.DataPropertyName = "Name";
      nameCol.Name = "Name";
      pluginsDataGrid.Columns.Add(nameCol);
 }
```

but I don't know how to set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn options. I gave it a try this way:

```
using (var depCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn())
{
    depCol.DataPropertyName = "Dependencies";
    depCol.Name = "Dependencies";
    pluginsDataGrid.Columns.Add(depCol);
}
```

where Dependencies is a list of strings. But it is not working. What kind of property should be assign to it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify DataSource for the column,  example:

```
        comboboxColumn.DataSource = collection;
        comboboxColumn.ValueMember = ColumnName;
        comboboxColumn.DisplayMember = ValueMember;
```

In your case use DataBindingComplete event to psecify collection:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Dependencies"];
        [Plugin_Type] entry = dataGridView1.Rows[i].DataBoundItem as [Plugin_Type];

        comboCell.DataSource = entry.[YOUR_PROPERTY];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, but I have just found some time to think of it. Well, I tried your approach, but I must be missing something as my comboBox is still empty. I noticed that if I additionaly add 2 lines of code in my init function:
`var dependenciesColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) pluginsDataGridView.Columns["pluginDependencies"];
            dependenciesColumn.DataPropertyName = "Dependencies";`
I will get na error obviously (everytime I try to hover on ComboBox, it says DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid), but in the same time then I can finally see wanted combobox options